# jQuery inconsistent loading of section elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple sections in my page each having their own id.
When the page has loaded I am trying to load the real Views for each of them from a Controller and place this into that section as per the sample code below.

However, whenever I refresh the page I find that sometimes the content arrives and sometimes it doesn't.  So sometimes I have content for all of them, then only for 2 or 3 then for all of them etc. What am I doing wrong?  The data coming back from the Controller is just a small bit of html.

Index.cshtml

```
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><section id="id1" class="ctrl1 mainPanel"></section></td>
        <td colspan="2"><section id="id2" class="ctrl2 mainPanel"></section></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><section id="id3" class="ctrl3 mainPanel"></section></td>
        <td><section id="id4" class="ctrl4 mainPanel"></section></td>
        <td><section id="id5" class="ctrl5 mainPanel"></section></td>
    </tr>
</table>

@section scripts {
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

     <script>

         $(document).ready(function () {

             $("#id1").load("/MyController/GetData1");
             $("#id2").load("/MyController/GetData2");
             $("#id3").load("/MyController/GetData3");
             $("#id4").load("/MyController/GetData4");

         });

    </script>
```

from the MyController:

```
public ActionResult GetData1()
{
    String s = "<b>Section 1 header</b><br><br>";
    s += "<ul><li>3 appointments</li><li>2 tasks</li></ul>";
    return Content(s);
}
```

etc...

Comment: Open up your browser's error or network console and see what's happening.  Maybe on a hard refresh your web server times out sometimes for some of the HTTP requests

Comment: inspect the AJAX requests in a browser console to see if they are being made, their status, data returned etc. Could also cut this to one request using `$.get`, and  have controller send back each outer `section` with same ID and parse the return data to insert it

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski On a refresh there are no timeouts - it simply isn't being called - could this have something to do with a limited number of HTTP handlers on the client?

Comment: Like now again - refresh and it skips the load of #id2 but the others load fine.  Do a refresh again and it skips #id4. Then refresh and all load ok, etc